# Arduino bluetooth HC-05 AT commands not working

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

After extensive research on several sites, I still can't e.g. change the name of my HC-05 bluetooth module with the Arduino Uno.
I hope you guys can help.

Settings can be changed by sending AT commands:
http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/HC-0305%20serail%20module%20AT%20commamd%20set%20201104%20revised.pdf

In the Arduino IDE I can not set baudrate 38400 in the serial monitor, but this doesn't matter, because I can check if the name is changed in the bluetooth settings on my phone.

The Arduino code:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");

  delay(2000);
}

void loop()
{

  // Keep reading from HC-05 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
  if (Serial.available())
    Serial.write(Serial.read());

  // Keep reading from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-05
  if (Serial.available())
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

After sending the command
`At+NAME=BLUE`
the name of the device is not changed to BLUE, but remains HC-05

I put the module in AT mode by pressing the button on the module and removing power, connecting power again and releasing the button. Now the LED is slowly blinking.

The name is not changed...

Comment: With a HC-06, I am able to change the name.
I also tried 2 other HC-05's, but still no response...

Answer (score 1):

To solve the 38400 baudrate issue, I downloaded an older version v1.6.0 from Arduino.

To solve the AT commands not working with a Arduino Uno issue, I uploaded the bareMinimum example and connected the bluetooth module rx port to rx and tx to tx. After selecting the correct baudrate (38400) and selecting "Both NL & CR" in the serial monitor, it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after two hours of hit-and-trial. The problem is that we are connecting the Rx of Arduino to Rx of HC-05 and likewise for Tx. What we have to actually do is to Connect Rx of Arduino to Tx of HC-05 and Tx of Arduino to Rx of HC-05. This will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Add some code to explain your answer, but otherwise, it is good :D

Comment: The solution doesn't require a code but if you want an exemplar code I'd be happy to share.

Comment: Just switch Rx an Tx connection on ardiuno board :)